# Derivative of integral - two functons of different variables

Tags: calculus

Let's say we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(z)$ where $x$ and $z$ are two different, unrelated variables.

Could anyone tell me why the following equality holds (if if does)?
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)dz=\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x)dz$$

Comment: The same thing is on both sides of the equals sign; is that what you meant?

Comment: @DylanSp Yes, and I'm wondering why it is equal. See [this page](http://emweb.unl.edu/NEGAHBAN/EM373/note19/note19.htm), in the part where it says 'Rearranging this relation and taking its time derivative relative to an inertial frame yields' - this is why I'm asking.

Comment: Well, the equality you posted holds because of reflexivity; $\forall{x}: x = x$. Is your question about the equation $m\vec{v}_{cm} = \int_{m} \vec{v}\, dm$?

Comment: I'm asking why time derivative of $\int_m \overrightarrow{r} dm$ is $\int_m \overrightarrow{v} dm$. I know that time derivative of position $r$ is velocity $v$, that's clear. Is $r$ a function of one or two variables? If two, then it shouldn't be that straightforward https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Wow, I completely spaced out; I missed that the derivative is outside the integral on the left and inside the integral on the right. Disregard my previous comments.

Comment: Looking at it more closely, I don't think it's true in general. There's going to be an extra constant term on the right side from integration; the differentiation on the left eliminates the constant of integration there.

Comment: @DylanSp not sure what you mean here. We differentiate both left and right side once so no matter what we get on the right side, be it a constant, it won't be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

This equality isn't quite true in general. There's going to be an extra constant term on the right side from integration; the differentiation on the left eliminates the constant of integration there.

Left hand side:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int f(x)\,dz &= \frac{d}{dx}(z \cdot f(x) + C_1) \\
&= z \cdot f'(x)
\end{align*}

Right hand side:
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{d}{dx}f(x)dz &= \int f'(x)\,dz \\
&= z \cdot f'(x) + C_2
\end{align*}